# Given that a royal flush occurs, what is the probability that it comes after a straight flush in a Poker Game??

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

I've revised the question after further exploration. Here is the information the is needed
The probability of a Straight Flush occurring is 0.00001540898529
The probability of a Royal Flush occurring is 0.000001540898529
I have changed the value of the Probability of a Straight Flush occurring overall because there's a rule in Poker that prohibits the use of cyclical hands. Basically, a player can't use the following hands:
Jack, Queen, King, Ace, 2
Queen, King, Ace, 2, 3
King, Ace, 2, 3, 4
For comparison, the original probability of a Straight Flush occurring was 0.00001539077 and the probability of a Royal Flush occurring was 0.000001539077.
Moving on, I am unsure whether I should be calculating the probability of a Royal Flush occurring FROM a Straight Flush OR the probability of a Royal Flush occurring AFTER a Straight Flush But only taking into account that the hand was removed from a standard deck of 52 cards. I have provided a Tree Diagram to illustrate both situations
Please note: If a Royal Flush occurs, I am only taking into account the fact that the first hand dealt was a Straight Flush but not a Royal Flush. However, I am still including the fact that a Royal Flush can occur within a Straight Flush. Please see the first image if you do and don't understand what I mean.
Lastly, I am using the equation for Conditional Probability to solve this, which would be P(A|B)=P(A intersection B)/P(B)
For those of you that may not remember, P(A intersection B) is just the values of A and B multiplied together
Let P(B) indicate the probability of a Royal Flush occurring OVERALL
Let P(A) indicate the probability of a Royal Flush given a Straight Flush.
Here are the tree diagrams:
[The probability of a Royal Flush Occurring from the Straight Flush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXmNO.png)

[Royal Flush occurring after a Straight Flush but only taking into account that the hand was removed from a standard deck of 52 cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq6ER.png)

Also, would I also need to revise my secondary values? Since the first 5-card removal is not replaced?

I hope this clarifies what I need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: a) You seem to be switching between "royal flush" and "full house". Which one do you want? b) At one point, you suddenly interject "excluding a Jack High Flush" in parentheses without explaining why, and at the end of that paragraph you suddenly talk about $36$ hands where you'd counted $40$ before (where $36$ would have been the count if you'd indeed excluded jack-high flushes for some reason). Please clarify.

Comment: I have clarified the question. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, going by the clear header rather than the rambling in the body, is that someone has been dealt a straight flush(excluding royal flush), and given that, you want to know your probablity of getting a royal flush.

- Out of $9$ possible such straight flushes from a suit, $4/9\; (23456,34567,45678,56789$)  allow you to get a royal flush from that suit, whereas $5/9$ don't
- So $4/9$ of the time, chances are open for $4$ royal flushes out of $47$ cards, wheras $5/9$ of the time they are open only for $3$ royal flushes.

Thus P(get Royal flush | straight flush has been dealt)

$$= {\frac49 *4 +\frac59*3\over \binom{47}5}, \approx 0.0002245 \,\%$$

Comment: Thank you, I took your opinion into account and revised my question. I apologize for my unnecessary rambling.